# finding a boolean circuit with AND, OR and NOT gates only

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, circuit

I am trying to find a Boolean circuit with AND, OR and NOT gates only to computes the Boolean function of ¬((A → ¬B) ∧ (C → A)). my attempt is :

[image]

Where I put arrows on two of the joints (where i believe "→ or Implies" goes in the function) is what I wanted to ask about how do I represent that on the circuit? Please guide me if I'm on the right track as Im new to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your Initial Expression: ¬((A → ¬B) ∧ (C → A))

Let's Break it down: A→B = ¬AvB
Applying that to your expression:

¬((¬Av¬B)∧(¬CvA))

Definition of Symbols:

¬ = NOT  v = OR  ∧ = AND

Now we need to decompose this expression:

1. The NOT outside the brackets means Apply the NOT operation to everything in the brackets (Essentially invert the value). We can ignore that for now and concentrate on whats in the brackets. New Expression:

(¬Av¬B)∧(¬CvA)

Once again this is made of two more sub expressions and means Apply the AND operation to the result of (¬Av¬B)and the result of(¬CvA). To do this we need to define the logic circuit for each of the expressions in the brackets.

Starting with (¬Av¬B):
[image]

Next, we find (¬CvA):
[image]

Now that we have defined them we can go back to our original sub expression of (¬Av¬B)∧(¬CvA). Now this tells us to combine the outputs of the logic circuits we have made using an AND Gate. To make this simpler to understand let's let (¬Av¬B) = E and (¬CvA) = F now we have the expression E∧F or E and F. See image below.
[image]

Now we have created a logic circuit for the expression (¬Av¬B)∧(¬CvA) which we can call G. Our original expression was ¬((¬Av¬B)∧(¬CvA)) which can be defined as ¬(G) or NOT(G) which is inverting (or applying a not gate) to the output of the logic circuit we have just made. See image Below:
[image]

As you can see there are multiple layers of 'abstraction' to creating a logic circuit which are defined by the brackets which compartmentalise the expression. How this helpes. Below are some further reading links that may help you:

Boolean algebra: wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Karnaugh graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Answer (score 1):

You cannot represent these points on the map: the one on the top is illegal because it connects an input to an intermediate output, while the one on the bottom wires two inputs together.

One approach is to replace implication X → Y with its logical equivalent ¬X ∨ Y inside the expression, and simplify the result:

¬((¬A ∨ ¬B) ∧ (¬C ∨ A))

Another approach you could take to solve this problem is to construct a truth table for the expression, put it in a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), and read the simplified expression composed of ANDs, ORs, and NOTs ([Canonical Disjunctive Normal Form).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form).